# Can a wild-shaped druid turn back to normal form and immediately attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, druid, actions, wild-shape

Let's say it's my turn, I'm in wild-shape form and I want to turn back to my normal form. Do I then sacrifice my ability to use an attack? If so, can I still do minor actions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It costs a Minor Action to Wild Shape. You still have a Standard Action (which most of your attack powers use) and a Move Action.  If you wish, you can convert either or both down to a Minor Action.